# C# XPath problem

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

When you run the following code, StatusCode is returned as null. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
        var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0'>
              <Response>
                <name>The Name</name>
                <Status>
                  <code>200</code>
                  <request>geocode</request>
                </Status>
              </Response>
            </kml>";

        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        ASCIIEncoding Enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        using (MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream(Enc.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            XmlDoc.Load(Stream);
        }
        XmlElement Root = XmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNamespaceManager XmlNS = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);
        XmlNS.AddNamespace("default", Root.NamespaceURI);
        XmlNode XmlResults = Root.SelectSingleNode("//default:Response", XmlNS);
        XmlNode StatusCode = XmlResults.SelectSingleNode("Status/code");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see by looking at the syntax coloring btw that CamelCasing local variables is pretty non-standard. The pascalCased "xml" looks better, just a thought :)

Comment: I believe you have your camelCasing and PascalCasing backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to supply the namespace to the elements further on, because they too are in the namespace.

```
XmlNode xmlResults = Root.SelectSingleNode("//default:Response", xmlNS);
XmlNode statusCode = XmlResults.SelectSingleNode("default:Status/default:code",
    xmlNS);
```